# "Attempt to read property "id" on array" when changing values on a <select>

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm having this bug using livewire and I really don't see what's the problem

In the class, I have a `$dominio_id` public variable declared where my component will bind. I have also a `$dominios` variable where I'm getting the data from the `Dominio` model, something as simple as...

```
class Software extends Component {
  public $dominio_id, $dominios; 
  ...

  public function mount() {
    $this->dominios = Dominio::orderBy('name')->get();
    $this->dominio_id = 1;
    ...
  }
}
```

In the blade, I have the following:

```
<select wire:model="dominio_id">
    @foreach ($dominios as $d)
        <option value="{{ $d->id }}">{{ $d->path }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

It renders fine, if I change the `dominio_id` to whatever id in the table, it gets selected, so no problems. Now, when I select a different value, it throws the error: `Attempt to read property "id" on array` the trace says the problem is here:

```
<option value="{{ $d->id }}">{{ $d->path }}</option>
```

If I take out the `wire:model` the problem goes away, but of course I can't bind the `select`.

I have done this very same thing lots of times, and never encountered this kind of error.

I tried also, while I know it isn't needed to add a `$rules` var:

```
protected $rules = [
  'dominio_id' => 'required',
];
```

But doesn't work either.

If I use the inspect tool, I see the `select - option` is well formed:

Any idea?

Comment: What is the result of var_dump($dominios)?

Comment: It throws a collection, and it is well done, it is what it was supposed to display. The problem is I can't vardump on the select change. It was throwing the exception immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options to solve that (one of these two options is enough):

1: remove `$this->dominios` from `mount()` and added in `render()` like this:

```
public function render(){
$dominios = Dominio::orderBy('name')->get();
return view('your-view',compact('dominios'));
}
```

2: in your blade you must use array instead of collection, like this:

```
<select wire:model="dominio_id">
    @foreach ($dominios as $d)
        <option value="{{ $d['id'] }}">{{ $d['path'] }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

the reason is livewire can't pass parameters by collection type to views (because js can't render that) , so when you use collection in `mount()`, livewire converted collection to array in next request.

Comment: The second worked, using it as an array. But I really don't get why this happened, I0ve done this kind of operation lots of times without a problem, must be a deeper bug somewhere else. The first one... didn't try, but why? Why should I make it this way?

Comment: since the livewire is a full-stack framework and must pass data from js to php and from php to js, livewire must only pass the types of data that support on both sides and js not supported collection... so your public property can not be type of collection (just public property transferred between js and php)