# Laravel 9 Livewire attempt to read property "id" on array

Tags: php, laravel-9, laravel-livewire

i'm new using php, and i keep getting error "attempt to read property "id" on array"

this my view list-monitors-get-show

```
<div>
    <x-loading-indicator></x-loading-indicator>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div>
            <p>
                <b>
                    Monitor 1
                </b>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <nav style="--falcon-breadcrumb-divider: url(&#34;data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='8' height='8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.5 0L1 1.5 3.5 4 1 6.5 2.5 8l4-4-4-4z' fill='%23748194'/%3E%3C/svg%3E&#34;);"
                aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Monitor 1</li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">Jenis Antrian</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body overflow-hidden p-2">
                    @forelse ($monitors as $monitor)
                    <a class="border-bottom-0 notification rounded-0 border-x-0 border border-300 w-100 mb-3"
                        wire:click.prevent="addItem({{ $monitor->ms_id }})">
                        <div class="notification-body">
                            <h5 class="fs-0">
                                {{ $monitor->ms_name }}
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    @empty
                    <a class="border-bottom-0 notification rounded-0 border-x-0 border border-300" href="#!">
                        <div class="notification-body">
                            <p class="mb-1">
                                no record found...
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    @endforelse
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h5 class="mb-0">Spesialis</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="table-responsive scrollbar containerme" id="items-container" style="position: relative; display: grid; grid-template-columns: auto auto auto; overflow:auto;">
                    <div style="height: 450px;">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-striped overflow-hidden">
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach ($polyclinics as $polyclinic)
                                <tr>
                                    <td wire:click="addSchedule({{ $polyclinic->id }})">
                                            <h6 class="fs--1" value={{ $polyclinic_id }}>{{ $polyclinic->name }}</h6>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="table-responsive scrollbar">
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped overflow-hidden">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Dokter</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($schedules as $schedule)
                            <tr class="align-middle">
                                <td class="text-nowrap">
                                    <h6 class="fs-0">
                                        {{ $schedule->full_name }}
                                        <span class="badge rounded-pill badge-soft-success">
                                            {{ $schedule->BpjsStart }} - {{ $schedule->BpjsEnd }}
                                        </span>
                                    </h6>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    

</div>
```

and my livewire controller getmonitor

```
public $state, $stateService, $schedules, $polyclinics = [];

    public $monitorId = 0;

    public $serviceId = 0;

    public $polyclinic_id = 0;

    public $isBPJS = 0;

    public function mount($id)
    {
        if ($id !== null) {
            $this->state = MonitorGetQueueItem::where('id', $id)->get();

            $this->state->toArray();

            $this->monitorId = $id;
            $this->schedules = [];
        } else {
            $this->state = [];
            $this->schedules = [];
            $this->polyclinics = [];
        }
    }

    public function addItem($id)
    {
        $BPJS = "Bpjs";
        $this->stateService = Service::where('id', $id)->get();
        if ($this->stateService[0]['clinic'] == 1) {
            if (stripos($this->stateService[0]['name'], $BPJS)) {
                $this->isBPJS = 1;
                $this->loadPolyClinic($this->isBPJS);
            } else {
                $this->isBPJS = 0;
                $this->loadPolyClinic($this->isBPJS);
            }
        } else {
            $this->loadPolyClinic();
        }
    }

    public function loadPolyClinic($isBPJS = null)
    {
        if ($isBPJS !== null) {

            $this->polyclinics = DB::connection("sqlsrv2")->table(DB::raw("(
                SELECT mmp.id,mmp.name,
                CASE WHEN rtds.bpjs_starttime <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isBpjs
                FROM reg_txn_doctor_schedule AS rtds
                LEFT OUTER JOIN mktg_mst_clinic AS mmc ON mmc.id = rtds.clinic_id
                LEFT OUTER JOIN mktg_mst_polyclinic AS mmp ON mmp.id = mmc.polyclinic_id
                WHERE 
                CONVERT(DATE,rtds.[date]) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
                AND rtds.[disabled]=0 
                AND rtds.inactive=0
                AND mmp.[type]='SPECIALIST'
                AND mmp.id NOT IN (68,64,67)
                GROUP BY mmp.id, mmp.name, rtds.bpjs_starttime) as a"))
                ->select("*")
                ->where('isBpjs', $isBPJS)
                ->groupBy('id', 'name', 'isBpjs')
                ->get();

        } else {
            $this->polyclinics = [];
        }
    }

    public function addSchedule($id)
    {
        $this->polyclinic_id = $id;
        $this->loadSchedule($this->polyclinic_id);
    }

    public function loadSchedule($id = null)
    {
        if ($id) {
            $this->schedules = DB::connection("sqlsrv2")->table(DB::raw("(SELECT
                    rtds.id AS schedule_id, 
                    mmmp.full_name,
                    mmp.name as polyclinic,
                    CASE WHEN rtds.bpjs_starttime-CAST(LTRIM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),GETDATE(),108))) AS INT) <= 120 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isStart,
                    CASE WHEN rtds.bpjs_starttime = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isBpjs,
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.cash_startime / 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.cash_startime % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as [CashStart],
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.cash_endtime / 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.cash_endtime % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as [CashEnd],
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.insurance_starttime / 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.insurance_starttime % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as [InsuranceStart],
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.insuranace_endtime / 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.insuranace_endtime % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as [InsuranceEnd],
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.bpjs_starttime / 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.bpjs_starttime % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as [BpjsStart],
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.bpjs_endtime / 60 AS VARCHAR),2)  + ':' +
                    RIGHT('0' + CAST(rtds.bpjs_endtime % 60 AS VARCHAR),2) as [BpjsEnd],
                    rtds.cash_allocated_offline_quota + rtds.insurance_allocated_offline_quota AS totalOffNb,
                    rtds.cash_used_offline_quota + rtds.insurance_used_offline_quota AS usedOffNb,
                    rtds.bpjs_allocated_offline_quota AS totalOffB, rtds.bpjs_used_offline_quota AS usedOffB,
                    rtds.cash_allocated_offline_quota + rtds.insurance_allocated_offline_quota + rtds.bpjs_allocated_offline_quota AS totalOff,
                    rtds.cash_used_offline_quota + rtds.insurance_used_offline_quota + rtds.bpjs_used_offline_quota AS usedOff
                    FROM reg_txn_doctor_schedule AS rtds 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mktg_mst_med_pract AS mmmp ON mmmp.id = rtds.doctor_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mktg_mst_clinic AS mmc ON mmc.id = rtds.clinic_id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN mktg_mst_polyclinic AS mmp ON mmp.id = mmc.polyclinic_id
                    WHERE 
                    CONVERT(DATE,rtds.[date]) = CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE())
                    AND rtds.[disabled] = 0
                    AND rtds.inactive = 0
                    AND mmp.id = $id) as b"))
                ->orderByRaw('b.CashStart ASC,b.CashEnd ASC')
                ->get();

            // dd($this->polyclinics, $this->polyclinic_id, $this->schedules);
        } else {
            $this->schedules = [];
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $monitorItem = MonitorGetQueueItem::selectRaw('mst_monitor_get_queue_item.id,mst_monitor_get_queue.id as mmgq_id, mst_monitor_get_queue.name as mmgq_name, mst_service.id as ms_id, mst_service.name as ms_name, mst_service.prefix')
            ->where('monitor_get_queue_id', $this->monitorId)
            ->where('mst_monitor_get_queue_item.disabled', 0)
            ->join('mst_monitor_get_queue', 'mst_monitor_get_queue.id', '=', 'mst_monitor_get_queue_item.monitor_get_queue_id')
            ->join('mst_service', 'mst_service.id', '=', 'mst_monitor_get_queue_item.service_id')
            ->get();

        // $this->polyclinics = $this->loadPolyClinic($this->isBPJS);
        // dd($this->polyclinics);

        return view('livewire.admin.monitors.list-monitors-get-show', [
            'monitors' => $monitorItem,
            'polyclinics' => $this->polyclinics,
            'schedules' => $this->schedules,
        ]);
    }
```

when i try dd($this->polyclinics); [this poly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjk9N.png)

when i try dd($this->schedules); [this schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S11V.png)

when i try to dd on function loadSchedule and addSchedule, i got schedules data. but when delete that dd. i got error "attempt to read property "id" on array"

i also tried to change

```
<td wire:click="addSchedule({{ $polyclinic->id }})">
```

to

```
<td wire:click="addSchedule({{ $polyclinic['id'] }})">
```

but i got error "cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

when I click 1 item on "Jenis Antrian"
[jenis antrian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw9a0.png)

success to show Spesialis items
[specialis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOYfP.png)

but when I click 1 item on specialise
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI0UU.png)

i want to show schedule data on that table
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCLs1.png)

Comment: Can you share `dd($this->polyclinics);` result?

Comment: @Vpa okay, this when i dd($this->polyclinics) https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjk9N.png

Comment: It should correct base on the dd() result. weird. one thing, why you use DB::raw, can't you do using Eloquent, because your code will be easy to inject.. check laravel how they prevent and can't prevent for SQL injection

Comment: I think the dd() you provide is incorrect, because you use groupBy in your code, but your image is shown different.. check again, I think you need 2 loop to get the 'ID'

Comment: see answer from this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76493608/attempt-to-read-property-id-on-array-when-changing-values-on-a-select/

Comment: @Vpa thanks for your advice to change from DB::raw to using Eloquent, and thank you for taking the time to give suggestions for my questions

Comment: @mohammadhosseingoli Thank you for taking the time to give suggestions for my questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing $polyclinic as an object.
I believe you mean to access it as an array so update the code within the "addSchedule" method to `$polyclinic['id']` ?

[image: snippet]

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give suggestions for my questions sir

Answer (score 0):

The same problem happened to me. I solved it by taking the search result and converting it into an array.

In my case, I received an array with StdClass objects so before sending the entire collection of objects, I used array_map to cast the objects into arrays. It worked